# CodeIgniter, adding parameter to form_open function

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to pass a paremeter to a form with form_open function but not like this :

```
$attr = array("id" => "$id");
form_open("my_page", $attr);
```

the parameter i need to pass is like (data-parsley-validate) :

```
<form action="my_page" method="post" data-parsley-validate>
```

and i don't know how to pass it to the form_open function. 
any help would be cool. 
thanks.

Comment: did you even try `$attr = array("data-parsley-validate" => "value");` before posting here?

Comment: Yes ... and as you can see, it's not a key/value pair, so it's not working.
it will add
    data-parsley-validate="value"
in the form declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a pre-built attributes string, it doesn't have to be an array:

```
form_open('your_page', 'data-parsley-validate');
```

... or just write the tag yourself, I don't understand why everybody insists on writing forms via function calls.

Comment: That did the trick thanks, even if it's not adding it at the end of the declaration. And yes when using a framework, i like to use the possibilities/facilities of it, if i have do it by hand, i will not use a framework and write the whole thing from scratch. and btw, it's my first attemps at using a framework ;) (i'm an old php coder from the times where frameworks where like the "future").  In all cases, thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, `form_open()` injects a CSRF token field too. But most of the other form helpers are only included for completeness ... you don't have to use all of the tools that the framework provides. `form_close()` for example is completely useless in that it just returns `</form>`.

Comment: I don't get it ... as i'm an old php coder wanting to know how all thoses things are working, i just got the "do it by yourself" thing ... ok i know how to do it but, what is the meaning of framework then ?

Comment: The framework is there to help you of course and I'm certainly not saying "do it all yourself", just that you don't have to depend on the framework if you don't really need to.